# Extbase can't import t3d data properly

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I'm just trying to import **t3d** export data on installing a distribution extension.For that i put my data.t3d export file under Initialisation folder in extbase extension.On installing the extension it creating the page tree properly, but no content is getting inserted and **tt_content** table is still empty.

But i can manually import that **t3d data** properly without any failure and content is getting properly inserted and **tt_content** table is getting populated correctly.Do any one have any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

The file should not be placed in the extbase extensions `Initialisation` folder, but in a subfolder of **your** extensions. Maybe your question is not accurate enough in that regard?

What does extbase has to do with your distribution?